# How to Join three table and write a query?

Tags: sql, join

Table 1:

```
Order_ID  Order_Type_ID    NAME      Date    
    1           1         Order1   03-07-16
    2           2         Order2   01-21-16
```

Table 2:

```
ID    Order_ID   Event_Date
1         1       03-21-16
2         2       03-21-16
```

Table 3:

```
ID    Order_Type_ID   Repeat_Number   Repeat_Sequence
1         1                3                 2W
2         2                2                 2M
```

I need to write a query by joining above three tables. In Table 1 I have list of orders with its type and date. Table 2 mainly store an event if order is sent. Table 3 has a cross reference of order types which indicates how many times an order needs to be sent and in what interval. Example: orders with type_Id 1 need to be sent three times every two weeks starting date of an order. Similarly, orders with type_Id 2 need to be sent two times every two months starting date of an order.

So based on event table (table 2) I need to write query to calculate how many times an order still needs to be sent and what is the next sent dates.

For example, query I need to write should display something like:

```
Order_ID     Sequence     NAME      Date    
    1           2        Order1   04-04-16
    1           3        Order1   04-18-16
    2           2        Order2   07-21-16
```

I can write it using sub queries but would like to know if there is any other smart and fast approach.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: In your expected output has one column "Sequence", its not in any of the table Table1, Table2 or Table3. Kindly narrate the Post in Clear cut format.

Comment: Sequence is an incremental number that should represent nth time order is begin sent. For example table 2 has an event for order_ID 1, which means order was sent one time and it need to be sent two more times i.e. sequence 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use recursive CTE for this. Assuming it is SQL Server, the query will be like this:

```
;with c as(
SELECT t1.Order_ID, t1.Order_Type_ID, t1.NAME, t1.Date, 
1 As Sequence, t3.Repeat_Number, t3.Repeat_Sequence
FROM #Table1 t1 INNER JOIN #Table3 t3 ON t1.Order_Type_ID = t3.Order_Type_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT c.Order_ID, c.Order_Type_ID, c.NAME, c.Date,
c.Sequence+1 As Sequence, c.Repeat_Number, c.Repeat_Sequence
FROM c WHERE c.Sequence < c.Repeat_Number)
select Order_ID, Order_Type_ID, Name, Sequence
, CASE WHEN Repeat_Sequence LIKE '%W' THEN DATEADD(week, Sequence * CAST(REPLACE(Repeat_Sequence, 'W', '') AS INT), Date)
       WHEN Repeat_Sequence LIKE '%M' THEN DATEADD(month, Sequence * CAST(REPLACE(Repeat_Sequence, 'M', '') AS INT), Date) END from c
order by Order_ID, Sequence
```

Result:

```
Order_ID    Order_Type_ID Name   Sequence    
----------- ------------- ------ ----------- -----------------------
1           1             Order1 1           2016-03-21 00:00:00.000
1           1             Order1 2           2016-04-04 00:00:00.000
1           1             Order1 3           2016-04-18 00:00:00.000
2           2             Order2 1           2016-03-21 00:00:00.000
2           2             Order2 2           2016-05-21 00:00:00.000

(5 row(s) affected)
```

If you want to see the future orders only then filter out any records less then today's date.

Please note that this query will work for Oracle or postgres with a small modification around the DATEADD function (In Postgres you will use INTERVAL, in Oracle you can just add 7 days for week, or use ADD_MONTHS for months)

**UPDATE:**

If you need to calculate the order dates based on the event date you can join it to the query like this:

```
;with c as(
SELECT t1.Order_ID, t1.Order_Type_ID, t1.NAME, t2.Event_Date, 
1 As Sequence, t3.Repeat_Number, t3.Repeat_Sequence
FROM #Table1 t1 INNER JOIN #Table3 t3 ON t1.Order_Type_ID = t3.Order_Type_ID
INNER JOIN #Table2 t2 ON t1.Order_ID = t2.Order_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT c.Order_ID, c.Order_Type_ID, c.NAME, c.Event_Date,
c.Sequence+1 As Sequence, c.Repeat_Number, c.Repeat_Sequence
FROM c WHERE c.Sequence < c.Repeat_Number)
select Order_ID, Order_Type_ID, Name, Sequence
, CASE WHEN Repeat_Sequence LIKE '%W' THEN DATEADD(week, Sequence * CAST(REPLACE(Repeat_Sequence, 'W', '') AS INT), Event_Date)
       WHEN Repeat_Sequence LIKE '%M' THEN DATEADD(month, Sequence * CAST(REPLACE(Repeat_Sequence, 'M', '') AS INT), Event_Date) END from c
order by Order_ID, Sequence
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I worked great. But, is it possible to decide and calculate next order data based on events in Table 2? because If I change Repeat_Sequence in table 3 output will change. So, based on events in table2 I need to calculate number of times order needs to be sent and next sent date should be calculated from Event_Date in table 2. Let me know if I'm not clear.